# Executing a cell function in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a custom cell function [=sortByWeek("Tasks")] that fetches data range from a different sheet and sorts it and prints it in the current sheet.

It's working great for the first time but i want to execute it every time data in the other sheet updates.

Here is the whole Script

```
function sortByWeek(sheetName) {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

        var range = sheet.getDataRange();
        var array = range.getValues();

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            // sort tasks by week number
            for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (array[i][2] < array[j][2]) {
                    var x = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = x;
                }
            }
        }

        // insert rows between different weeks;
        var arrayFinal = [];
        let same = array[0][2];
        let total = 0;
        for (var e = 0; e < array.length; e++) {
            var string = [[""],["QWERTY", "", "", "Week " + same + " total", total, "x", ""],[""]];
            
            if (array[e][2] === same) {
                total = total + array[e][4];
                arrayFinal.push(array[e]);
            } else {
                if (!(e === 0)) {
                    for (var s = 0; s < string.length; s++) {
                        arrayFinal.push(string[s]);
                        total = 0;
                    }
                }
                arrayFinal.push(array[e]);
            }
            same = array[e][2];
        }
        for (var s = 0; s < string.length; s++) {
            arrayFinal.push(string[s]);
        }
        return arrayFinal;
    }
```

Comment: Share a link to your spreadsheet, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "Tasks" is the name of the sheet (tab), try

=sortByWeek("Tasks", Tasks!A:Z)

The second parameter is a 'dummy' parameter: it is not used in the custom function but will force a recalculation of the custom formula if the range (indicated in that second parameter) is edited.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying enough! "Tasks" is the name of the sheet where the data comes from!

Comment: Then try something like the updated formula above and see if that works. Change range to suit.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple! Thank you so much!!